# Rails: ArgumentError: Unrecognized status code :request_entity_too_large

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-status-code-413

In my Rails controller, in a method that handles an HTTP POST, I'm trying to write code that'll return an HTTP 413 response to the client if the value of the `data` param in the request payload is too large.

Per several [sources](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails%20http%20status%20codes) (e.g. [1](http://www.railsstatuscodes.com/), [2](https://gist.github.com/mlanett/a31c340b132ddefa9cca)), the Rails symbol for HTTP 413 is `:request_entity_too_large`.

My line of code is:

```
head :request_entity_too_large and return if too_large?(params[:data])
```

(`too_large?` is a private method that I have defined elsewhere in my controller.)

This line is throwing this error at runtime: `ArgumentError: Unrecognized status code :request_entity_too_large`.

I have a similar line of code that instead returns `:unsupported_media_type`; that one  *is* working as expected.

What's the problem with my line that attempts to return `:request_entity_too_large`?

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4.2, `:request_entity_too_large` was renamed to `:payload_too_large`. Use the latter instead. For example, this works in Rails 4.2+:

```
head :payload_too_large and return if is_too_large?(params[:data])
```

Source: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_2_release_notes.html#changed-status-option-symbols-for-render